# JavaFx Jfoenix JFXpasswordField Exception

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

When i try to get password value from JfxpasswordField i get the exception bellow. After doing Research i came across a solution which suggested i use scene bulder 8.5 but unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. Kindly assists in resolving this issue

below is the code caption producing the error .The error is occuring in this line

```
PasswordValue = password.getText();
```

here is the code snippet

```
package com.kayseensystems.posmaxpro;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField;
import com.kayseensystems.posmaxpro.Datalayer.User;
import com.kayseensystems.posmaxpro.Services.LonginService;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField;
@Controller
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @Autowired
    private LonginService longinService;
    @FXML
    private JFXPasswordField password;

    @FXML
    private JFXTextField username;

    @FXML
    private void loginButton(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
       String usernamevalue=username.getText();
       String PasswordValue;
        PasswordValue = password.getText();
        System.out.println("Username="+usernamevalue+" "+PasswordValue);
        try {
        User user=longinService.SystemLogin(usernamevalue,PasswordValue);
        if(user==null){
            Notifications notify=Notifications.create()
                    .title("Login").text("The provided user does Not Exist.Kindly consult Management")
                    .graphic(null).hideAfter(Duration.seconds(5))
                    .position(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
            notify.showError();
        }else{
            Notifications notify=Notifications.create()
                    .title("Login").text("Logged in Successful")
                    .graphic(null).hideAfter(Duration.seconds(5))
                    .position(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
            notify.showInformation();
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.getCause().printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Error Stack trace

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
     at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
     at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
     at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
     at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown Source)
     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
     ... 48 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.kayseensystems.posmaxpro.FXMLController.loginButton(FXMLController.java:50)
     ... 58 more
    2018-07-18 01:40:51.735  WARN 6444 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=3m21s762ms818µs939ns).
    2018-07-18 02:06:33.846  INFO 6444 --- [lication Thread] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
    2018-07-18 02:06:33.851  INFO 6444 --- [lication Thread] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
    2018-07-18 07:48:57.461  WARN 6444 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=5h12m35s558ms294µs497ns).
```

here is fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Lighting?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Shadow?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" fx:id="FXMLController" prefHeight="594.0" prefWidth="779.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.kayseensystems.posmaxpro.FXMLController">
    <children>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="-11.0" layoutY="-6.0" prefHeight="594.0" prefWidth="349.0" style="-fx-background-color: #6a5acd;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="6.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="-6.0">
            <children>
                <ImageView fx:id="image1" cache="true" fitHeight="73.0" fitWidth="155.0" focusTraversable="true" pickOnBounds="true" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../icons/Capture.JPG" />
                    </image>

                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
                    </VBox.margin>
                </ImageView>
                <Label prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="94.0" text="Welcome To" textAlignment="RIGHT" textFill="WHITE" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Eras Bold ITC" size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                    <effect>
                        <Lighting>
                            <bumpInput>
                                <Shadow />
                            </bumpInput>

                        </Lighting>
                    </effect>
                </Label>
                <Label text="Pos Max Pro" textFill="WHITE" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Impact" size="24.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
            </children>
        </VBox>
        <Pane layoutX="393.0" prefHeight="594.0" prefWidth="434.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFF;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="345.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <ImageView fx:id="image2" fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="201.0" layoutX="7.0" layoutY="6.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@../../../icons/innerview.JPG" />
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
                <Label layoutX="32.0" layoutY="144.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="138.0" text="Welcome Back">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="18.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>
                <Label layoutX="36.0" layoutY="167.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="124.0" text="sign in to continue" />
                <Hyperlink fx:id="signup" layoutX="171.0" layoutY="424.0" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="110.0" text="Sign up here" textFill="SLATEBLUE">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="16.0" />
                    </font>
                </Hyperlink>
                <Hyperlink fx:id="passwordchange" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="424.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="117.0" text="forgot password" textFill="ROYALBLUE">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                    </font>
                </Hyperlink>
                <Button fx:id="Login" layoutX="35.0" layoutY="493.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#loginButton" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="110.0" style="-fx-background-color: #00CED1; -fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-border-radius: 10;" text="Button" textFill="WHITE">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Ebrima Bold" size="22.0" />
                    </font>
                </Button>
                <JFXTextField fx:id="username" focusColor="#6747cd" labelFloat="true" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="276.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="241.0" promptText="username" unFocusColor="#6747cd" />
            <JFXPasswordField id=" password" fx:id="password" labelFloat="true" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="364.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="241.0" promptText="Password" />
            </children>
        </Pane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post your FXML as well.

Comment: Don't seem to find anything really wrong here. You probably have to make a [mcve].

Comment: I just tested it and `PasswordValue = password.getText();` is not the line throwing a NPE (`com.kayseensystems.posmaxpro.FXMLController.loginButton(FXMLController.java:50)`). For this line to throw the NPE `password` would have to be `null`. My assumption is that you accidentally posted the wrong line of code the line causing the exception (`com.kayseensystems.posmaxpro.FXMLController.loginButton(FXMLController.java:50)`). It's probably `e.getCause().printStackTrace();` that's throwing the exception since the exception doesn't have a cause listed...

Comment: Thank you for your response @Fabian but i have discovered that am able to get both username and password from The UI but the username and password am providing do not exist in my database.According the code snippet provided above this causes the code execution to fall under code block user==null. I Am unable to trace the actual line where the exception is being thrown. Any assistance accorded will be appreciated

Comment: Why catch the exception, if you rethrow it anyways? This just obscures the source of the issue. You should at least wrap the exception in a new one: `throw new Exception("Something went wrong", e);`